# FTP saying "Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined" nodejs

Tags: node.js, ftp, connection

I'm trying to send files from local to a FTP server.
After connect I receive this error:

```
if (!isBuffer && input.pause !== undefined)
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined
```

**In ftp/lib/connection (line 946)**

My connection code:

```
  let ftpClient = new ftp();
  let file = req.query.archive;

  ftpClient.on('ready', function(){
    ftpClient.put(file, ftpConfig.path, function(err){
    if(err){
      res.redirect('http://localhost:3003/api/v1/sendftp');
      console.log('You got an error:\n', err)
    }
    ftpClient.end();
    });
  });

  ftpClient.connect(ftpConfig.ftp);
```

Comment: Where is `input` coming from? What is the relevant code around `input`?

Comment: Thist ```input``` comes from the ftp lib, they need an filestream inside